# Problem with my textarea in the form on my website

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, textarea

I'm new here :)

I've been trying to built a form with 2 inputs and one textarea. When I check the inputs, everything goes fine, but the problem occurs when I try to submit my form. Even though the textarea field is not empty, the function doesn't change my border into green color, and the text in  below doesn't dissaper.
On the other hand, when I put an eventlistener while checking inputs - form closes, after filling textarea with any letter.
I cannot think of any solution, I would like an eventlistener to work exactly the same as it works on inputs.
I hope you understand my problem, I attach my code to show you my point of view.
Hope I get some answers from you! :)
Thanks!

```js
// Formularz - the form
 
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const yourName = document.getElementById('name');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const msg = document.getElementById('message');
 
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkInputs();
})
 
yourName.addEventListener('input', () => {
    checkInputs();
})
email.addEventListener('input', () => {
    checkInputs();
})
 
function checkInputs() {
  const yourNameValue = yourName.value.trim(); 
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const msgValue = msg.value.trim();
 
     
  if(yourNameValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(yourName, 'Name is required')
  }
  else {
    setSuccesFor(yourName);
  }
  if(emailValue === "") {
      setErrorFor(email, 'Email is required')
  }
  else if(!isEmail(emailValue)) {
      setErrorFor(email, 'Email is not valid')
  }
  else {
      setSuccesFor(email)
  }
  if (msgValue === "") {
      setTextError(msg, 'Message is required')
  }
  else {
      setTextSuccess(msg)
  }
   
  // zamykanie formularza - closing the form
   
  if (yourNameValue && emailValue && msgValue) {
     form.classList.add('close');
  }
 
}
function setTextError(textarea, message) { // funkcja odpowiedzialna za textarea - function responsible for textarea
    const formControl = textarea.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
                                                         
    small.innerText = message;
    formControl.className = 'form-control error';
}
function setTextSuccess(textarea) {
    const formControl = textarea.parentElement;
 
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}
 
function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement; 
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small')
 
    // add error message inside small
    small.innerText = message;
    // add error class
    formControl.className = 'form-control error';
}
function setSuccesFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}
 
function isEmail(email) {
    return /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(email);
}
```

```css
.form-parent {
   background-color: lightblue;
   color: white;
}
textarea {
    resize: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
form {
   display: block;
   margin-top: 20px;
   padding: 20px 20px 0;
}
input, label, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}
.form-control label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: black;
}
.form-control input {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}
.form-control {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#submit {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    margin:10px 0 20px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
    border: solid white 1px;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
small {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
    color: rgb(182, 19, 19);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
/* input check */
.form-control.success input { 
    border: 2px solid green;
}
.form-control.error input {
    border: 2px solid rgb(182, 19, 19);
}
.form-control.error textarea {
    border: 2px solid rgb(182, 19, 19);
}
/* textarea check */
.form-control.success textarea {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
.form-control.error small {
    visibility: visible;
}
/* zamykanie formularza */ - closing the form
form.close {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-parent">
    <form action="/" method="get">
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
            <small></small>
        </div>
       <div class="form-control">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="email">
        <small></small>
       </div>
       <div class="form-control">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" cols="10" rows="10"></textarea>
        <small></small>
       </div>  
        <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the form never gets submitted, and the `close` is added whenever all three fields are filled (you might add textarea minimum characters check)... The problem seems to be the submitting. Try this:

- add input listener for textarea
- when setting `close`, also return true to submit check method, which will indicate that the form is valid, and then submit the form programmatically from there
- change submit button's `submit` id to `submit-btn` in HTML and CSS, to allow `form.submit` method

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const yourName = document.getElementById('name');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const msg = document.getElementById('message');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const check = checkInputs();
  if (check) form.submit();
})

yourName.addEventListener('input', () => {
  checkInputs();
})
email.addEventListener('input', () => {
  checkInputs();
})
msg.addEventListener('input', () => {
  checkInputs();
})

function checkInputs() {
  const yourNameValue = yourName.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const msgValue = msg.value.trim();


  if (yourNameValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(yourName, 'Name is required')
  } else {
    setSuccesFor(yourName);
  }

  if (emailValue === "") {
    setErrorFor(email, 'Email is required')
  } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
    setErrorFor(email, 'Email is not valid')
  } else {
    setSuccesFor(email)
  }

  if (msgValue === "") {
    setTextError(msg, 'Message is required')
  } else {
    setTextSuccess(msg)
  }

  // zamykanie formularza - closing the form

  if (yourNameValue && emailValue && msgValue) {
    form.classList.add('close');
    return true;
  }

}

function setTextError(textarea, message) { // funkcja odpowiedzialna za textarea - function responsible for textarea
  const formControl = textarea.parentElement;
  const small = formControl.querySelector('small');

  small.innerText = message;
  formControl.className = 'form-control error';
}

function setTextSuccess(textarea) {
  const formControl = textarea.parentElement;

  formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  const small = formControl.querySelector('small')

  // add error message inside small
  small.innerText = message;
  // add error class
  formControl.className = 'form-control error';
}

function setSuccesFor(input) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}

function isEmail(email) {
  return /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(email);
}
```

```css
.form-parent {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

form {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
}

input,
label,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.form-control label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: black;
}

.form-control input {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.form-control {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#submit-btn {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  border: solid white 1px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

small {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: rgb(182, 19, 19);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/* input check */

.form-control.success input {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.form-control.error input {
  border: 2px solid rgb(182, 19, 19);
}

.form-control.error textarea {
  border: 2px solid rgb(182, 19, 19);
}


/* textarea check */

.form-control.success textarea {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.form-control.error small {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* zamykanie formularza */

- closing the form form.close {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-parent">
  <form action="/" method="get">
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
      <small></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="email" type="email">
      <small></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea id="message" cols="10" rows="10"></textarea>
      <small></small>
    </div>
    <button id="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```